# Forge viewer: how to fix 'toggleVisibility' of undefined for Hidden models selected from model browser?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk forge viewer 7.2.0 version and trying to load multiple models. For few of the models I am using the modelOption 'loadAsHidden: true' with which the model will be hidden but added in the model browser as expected (eye icon is active but I think it should be inactive).
After loading the viewer when I click on eye icon of the hidden model, I want the model to be loaded in the viewer but I am getting following error:

```
core.js:12501 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleVisibility' of undefined
    at MultiModelVisibilityManager.LMV../src/tools/VisibilityManager.js.MultiModelVisibilityManager.toggleVisibility (viewer3D.js:84086)
    at GuiViewer3D.LMV../src/application/Viewer3D.js.Viewer3D.toggleVisibility (viewer3D.js:33306)
    at ViewerModelStructurePanel.LMV../src/gui/ViewerModelStructurePanel.js.ViewerModelStructurePanel.onEyeIcon (viewer3D.js:67026)
    at ModelStructureTreeDelegate.<anonymous> (viewer3D.js:62564)
```

With further investigation I found the visibilityManager for the hidden model is being null which is causing the issue but when I do the viewer.showModel(hiddenModel), then it has the visibilityManager in place and model browser works as expected.

I expected that when eye icon of hidden model clicked then it should internally do the showModel() and load the model to viewer. Can someone please suggest me if I am looking it differently or suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can piggyback the `onEyeIcon` handler like below:

```
viewer.modelstructure.onEyeIcon = function(dbId, model) {
        this.viewer.showModel(model);
        this.viewer.toggleVisibility(dbId, model);
    };
```

**Edit:**

To sync the eye icon in the structure panel you can manually initialize the visibility manager and flip the visibility of model root there - can do in any of the post model load lifecycle which would be entirely imperceptible to end users:

```
NOP_VIEWER.loadModel(svfURL, options, ()=>{
const model = NOP_VIEWER.impl.modelQueue().getHiddenModels()[0];
model.visibilityManager = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VisibilityManager(NOP_VIEWER.impl, model);
model.visibilityManager.toggleVisibility(sb.getRootId())
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great but I have following issues related to same topic:
1) The models hidden initially with the modelOption 'loadAsHidden', have eyeIcon active already in the model browser which is not in sync with the model in viewer.
2) For enabling search box in mobile devices, I am using ```this.viewer.setModelStructurePanel(new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerModelStructurePanel(this.viewer, 'Model browser', {hideSearch: false}))```. I think because of this the model structure is rebuilt and the hidden model is not listed in the model browser.

Can you help me solving this?

Comment: See edit and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022319/how-to-enable-search-for-the-model-structurue-panel-with-forge-viewer/58022320#58022320) for the other question

Comment: works perfectly!, thanks a lot for the quick response and solution