# How to enable search for the model structurue panel with Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk

By default search is disabled for the model structure panel on mobile devices...

For enabling search box in mobile devices, I am using

```
this.viewer.setModelStructurePanel(new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerModelStructurePanel(this.viewer, 'Model browser', {hideSearch: false})).
```

I think because of this the model structure is rebuilt and hidden model is not listed in the model browser. Can you help me solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the missing model back programmatically with

```
var model = NOP_VIEWER.impl.modelQueue().getHiddenModels()[0]
NOP_VIEWER.modelstructure.addModel(model)
```

And you might want to round out the missing configuration for your new model panel as well:

```
new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerModelStructurePanel(this.viewer, 'Model browser', {
  docStructureConfig: viewer.config.docStructureConfig,
  hideSearch: false,
  excludeRoot: viewer.config.modelBrowserExcludeRoot,
  startCollapsed: viewer.config.modelBrowserStartCollapsed,
  isolate: viewer.config.modelBrowserIsolateSelectedNodes
})
```